# How to access launchEnvironment and launchArguments set in XCUIApplication, running UI tests in XCode?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ui-testing

I've tried setting attributes in the `XCUIApplication` instance, in my UI Tests `setUp()`

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
app.launchEnvironment = ["testenv" : "testenvValue"]
app.launchArguments = ["anArgument"]
app.launch()
```

in `didFinishLaunch` I've tried to show these on screen when I run my UITests

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    if launchOptions != nil {
        for (key, value) in launchOptions! {  
            let alertView = UIAlertView(title: key.description, message: value.description, delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "ok")
            alertView.show()
        }
    }
```

But I can't seem to be able to find the arguments and environment I set. Anyone know how to get a hold of them?

Comment: Yea I can't find them either--wish there was more documentation on a lot of this stuff. It's cool just.. hard to get some good tests going.

Comment: Hi, do you by any chance know if any example of how to use ```launchArguments``` exists on apple web-site? The official documentation is just killing me: ```The arguments that will be passed to the application on launch``` (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuiapplication/1500477-launcharguments). As if it's not obvious from name

Answer (score 73):

If you set `launchArguments` in a UI Test (Swift):

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
app.launchArguments.append("SNAPSHOT")
app.launch()
```

Then read them in your App using:

**swift 2.x**:

```
if NSProcessInfo.processInfo().arguments.contains("SNAPSHOT") {
   // Do snapshot setup
}
```

**Swift 3.0**

```
if ProcessInfo.processInfo.arguments.contains("SNAPSHOT") {
}
```

To set environment variables, use `launchEnvironment` and  `NSProcessInfo.processInfo().environment`, respectively, instead.

Comment: Under Xcode 7.3 this does not seem to be working. I've tried set launchArguments and then read them straight back. I always get back and empty array. Even if I do it on the very next line. Looks like they may be broken. Same for launchEnvironment.

Comment: Make sure you have only one XCUIApplication instance and call launch *after* setting launchArguments.

Comment: When `Record UI Test` in Xcode, it doesn't run `setUp()`. It misleads me the above codes not working. But run the UI test again (not `Record UI Test` mode), it works.

Comment: In case any one else is banging their head as I was because it still wasn't working, the Build Configuration must also be set to Debug. If set to Release it will have empty launch arguments.

Answer (score 20):

It's also interesting to note that arguments passed to `XCUIApplication.launchArguments` are also available from `UserDefaults`.

**In your XCTestCase**

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
app.launchArguments.append("-ToggleFeatureOne")
app.launchArguments.append("true")
app.launch()
```

**In your target under test**

```
UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "ToggleFeatureOne") // returns true
```

From here you could create extensions on `UserDefaults` to provide handy run time toggles.

This is the same mechanism the Xcode schemes "arguments passed on launch" uses. Launch arguments and their effect on `UserDefaults` are documented under [Preferences and Settings Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/AboutPreferenceDomains/AboutPreferenceDomains.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000059i-CH2-SW1).

Comment: I seem to be doing what you suggest here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77134277/setting-user-default-values-programatically-in-uitest - however, The user default value doesn't get set. Any idea what I could be doing wrong ?

Answer (score 17):

Building on Joey C.'s answer, I wrote a small extension to avoid using raw strings in the app. This way you avoid any typo issue and get autocompletion.

```
extension NSProcessInfo {
    /**
     Used to recognized that UITestings are running and modify the app behavior accordingly

     Set with: XCUIApplication().launchArguments = [ "isUITesting" ]
     */
    var isUITesting: Bool {
        return arguments.contains("isUITesting")
    }

    /**
     Used to recognized that UITestings are taking snapshots and modify the app behavior accordingly

     Set with: XCUIApplication().launchArguments = [ "isTakingSnapshots" ]
     */
    var isTakingSnapshots: Bool {
        return arguments.contains("isTakingSnapshots")
    }
}
```

This way you can use

```
if NSProcessInfo.processInfo().isUITesting {
   // UITesting specific behavior,
   // like setting up CoreData with in memory store
}
```

Going further, the various arguments should probably go into an enum that could be reused in the UITest when setting the launchArguments.

Comment: Can now be renamed to ProcessInfo

Answer (score 11):

Here is example with launchArguments and Objective-C:

```
if ([[NSProcessInfo processInfo].arguments containsObject:@"SNAPSHOT"]) {
        //do snapshot;
}
```

Swift:

```
    let arguments = ProcessInfo.processInfo.arguments
    if arguments.contains("SNAPSHOT") {
        //do snapshot
    }
```

Comment: Hi! Where do I find a list of al supported launch arguments?

Answer (score 8):

For launch arguments, pass them as two separate arguments:

```
let app = XCUIApplication()  
app.launchArguments.append("-arg")  
app.launchArguments.append("val")  
app.launch()
```

Taken from [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/14438).

Answer (score 7):

Bear in mind a few details. Firstly, XCUIAppliction is not a singleton, therefore, if you call `XCUIApplication().arguments.append("myargument")` and then you call `XCUIApplication().launch()`, it won't send the arguments. [Check it here](https://web.archive.org/web/20180625191226/http://drekka.ghost.io/xcuiapplication-youre-probably-doing-it-wrong/).

Second, if you modify the arguments after launching the app it won't work, it will send the new arguments to the next execution.

Comment: This is the answer than actually solves the problem and explains why.

Answer (score 4):

I'm only aware of how this works in Objective-C

```
NSDictionary *environment = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] environment];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need pass the **environment variables** from your schema to XCUITes, modify the XCTestCase -> app.launchEnvironment object, on each test class of this way:

**Swift 3**

```
override func setUp(){
    app.launchEnvironment = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1- Create an extension of ProcessInfo

```
extension ProcessInfo {

    public enum LaunchArgument: String {
        case uiTestSampleData
        case uiTestStagingData
        case none
    }

    public var launchArgument: LaunchArgument {
    
        if arguments.contains(LaunchArgument.uiTestSampleData.rawValue) {
            return .uiTestSampleData
        }
    
        if arguments.contains(LaunchArgument.uiTestStagingData.rawValue) {
            return .uiTestStagingData
        }
    
        return .none
    }

}
```

2- Modify your data source init. In this case I am using Moya, so I modify the provider init.
Instead of initing your rest api normally, in the init check the arguments and mock the responses for sameplData arguments.

```
public init(provider: MyProvider<MyStoreApi> = MyProvider<MyStoreApi>()) {
    
    switch ProcessInfo.processInfo.launchArgument {
        
    case .uiTestSampleData:
        let provider = MyProvider<MyStoreApi>(stubClosure: MoyaProvider.immediatelyStub)
        self.provider = provider
        
    case .none, .uiTestStagingData:
        self.provider = provider
    }

}
```

3- In UI test add the argument

```
app.launchArguments.append("uiTestSampleData")
```