# Swift - Why Process.arguments returns empty array

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, xcode-ui-testing

I'm doing some UI testing in my iOS app but I'm seeing some strange behaviour.

In my `setUp()` method I'm adding some values to `XCUIApplication().launchArguments` but when I query to see the launch arguments, I'm getting and empty array.

This is how my `setUp()` method looks like:

```
override func setUp() {
    super.setUp()

    let application = XCUIApplication()
    application.launchArguments = ["USE_SERVER_DEBUG"]
    application.launch()
}
```

This is the function that calls `Process.arguments` to retrieve the arguments

```
func checkArguments(){
    let launchArguments = Process.arguments
    for index in 0 ..< launchArguments.count {
        let argument = launchArguments[index] as String

        if argument.compare("USE_DEBUG_SERVER") == NSComparisonResult.OrderedSame {
            // Do something
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: I don't know anything about Automation, but check this answer out.  It appears that you may not be accessing the proper process.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/33335994/1671729

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if `Process` is your own class or a typo, but you should be using `NSProcessInfo`.

```
if NSProcessInfo.processInfo().arguments.contains("USE_SERVER_DEBUG") {
    // Do something
}
```

Also, I usually recommend against *setting* the launch arguments. Instead, you should *append* to them. But that's more of a best practice than anything.

```
application.launchArguments += "USE_SERVER_DEBUG"
```

Comment: `Process` is Swift's "command-line arguments for the current process".